# string from php script to flash

Tags: php, flash

I'm using facebook php sdk to get friend list of an user. But I'm strugling to get that list to flash.

The idea is that the list is always new, depending from the user loading the application. So what I need is one .html file which is loaded with php script to proccess friend list and embedded flash .swf to which php would pass information.

How can I achieve this? thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data sharing between users using flash and php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681056/data-sharing-between-users-using-flash-and-php)

Comment: or alternatively [Request data in a Flash movie from PHP, at run-time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/970371) (different approach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

Set the [flashvars](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html) to the data you want to pass to the Flash file. Since the friend list rarely changes, that should work.

Or use a `URLLoader`:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://example.com/yourscript.php");
loader.addEventListener("complete", loader_complete);
loader.loader(request);

private function loader_complete(event:Event):void {
    var scriptData:String = event.currentTarget.data;
    // process data
}
```