# how to communicate between php and flash

Tags: php, actionscript-3, web, flash

I have a php file which looks like this.

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['username']= ________;//Get data from swf file
$_SESSION['password']=_________;//Get data from swf file
?>

<!------EMBEDDING SWF FILE--->
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="flashContent">
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="1024" height="600" id="indexFLA" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="indexFLA.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to set the `$_SESSION[]` variables using the actionscript3 in the embedded flash file.

I know that you can use `URLRequest("file.php")` to communicate with external php but I am not sure how this will work to communicate with the php the swf file itself is in.

How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried flash vars: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your flash file is not in PHP :). You just embed the object in HTML code printed by PHP.

Now, as for communication between flash and PHP:

- An example how to send variable from PHP to flash during flash code execution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7620511/2028547 - you essentially load PHP file that contains your content.
- And ex example how to send variable from Flash to PHP: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4215407

Basically: To pass a variables by loading a page (either with POST data being sent or proper content being printed out)

Also you NEVER should pass sensitive data, like user name and password, by simply using [flashvars](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html) (aka. embedding it in HTML code like you asked) - equally well you can print in on the screen. It's completely insecure. You should pass encrypted data (or better: only a checksums) during code execution. NOT in a way that can be read by anyone who knows how to view source code of a webpage.

Comment: what do you mean my flash file is not in php? Do you mean to say that when I load `thisFile.php` using `URLRequest()`, I would not get all the html code back in flash, and only what I print within the `<?php?>`.

Comment: @AnkurSharma I mean that you embed the flash onto a webpage using HTML. PHP doesn't have anything to deal with it besides being responsible for printing the HTML code. As for getting the HTML code - using URLRequest you can pass more than one variable. So pass a var "flash" = "1" and in PHP check if `$_REQUEST['flash']==1` if so than print only the response and die without printing any HTML.

Comment: Also I really hope that you don't have your `<?php` randomly in the middle of HTML code as that's one of the worst things you can do in working on PHP files. If you have PHP file - make it control whole content output. Do not play with php in the middle of HTML content. It's wrong in many ways. One you just discovered - you cannot control what is being printed out before php kicks in.

Comment: So do you mean that is should put my html code within the `<?php?>` and `print` it if `$_REQUEST['flash']==false`

Comment: Basically: yes. If you have PHP file you always should have HTML content IN PHP, being `echo`ed by PHP. Especially if you just start with PHP and don't know really how to handle situations like that well. It'll make your life much easier in future :)

Comment: Thanks very much, but when I try to `echo "<html><!-----htmlcode------></html>"`, it gives me parse error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'`. Do I need to write my my html differently when echoing it in php?

Comment: Make sure you handle quotes correctly and got semicolons in right places. Error you get got nothing to deal with `echo`, but rather how you output your code. Most likely you have `"` sign in HTML causing issues. Try [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for outputting long text data.

Comment: Yupp, works. Thanks very much. heredoc syntax does the trick.

Comment: I am stuck on one more question though- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040704/how-to-set-request-from-actionscript3