# How to set parameters like $_POST or $_REQUEST from actionscript3?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, web

I am trying to communicate with a php file from within the flash.

I want to set the `$_REQUEST['setData']= "true"` from the flash file. Here is my php code.

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST['setData']=="true")
{
    echo "setData";
}
?>
```

What I have in actionscript3 code so far -

```
        var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("php/index.php");
        phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        phpFileRequest.data = phpVars;

        var phpLoader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
        phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);
        phpLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityError);
        phpLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError);
        phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

        phpVars.email = email.text;
        phpVars.password = password.text;

        phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest)
```

How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: `$_REQUEST` is the union of URL query parameters, POST parameters and cookies. Set any of these in your request.

Comment: @deceze so how would i set the post parameter? sry i am a newb

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about Actionscript. You should rephrase your question to ask this exactly to target the right people who do know Actionscript, but may have no idea what `$_REQUEST` is.

Comment: Try $_FORM['setData']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from reading your code, no knowledge of AS, I am guessing here

```
    var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("php/index.php");

    phpVars.email = email.text;
    phpVars.password = password.text;
    phpVars.setData= 'true';//**************** LOOK HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    phpFileRequest.data = phpVars;

    var phpLoader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
    phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);
    phpLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityError);
    phpLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError);
    phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;


    phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest)
```